# How to trigger distribution module when rebuilding sub module in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Hi say we have the following project structure

```
Parent
  |
  +----> module 1
  |
  +----> module 2
  |
  +----> module 3
  |
  +----> distribution module
```

Normally, we build the parent and distribute the final war file we got from the distribution module, which includes all the other three modules.

If I only made changes to module 2, I dont want to build from the parent, instead, I want to rebuild module 2 only and I want the distribution module to build as well to get the new module 2.

How do you setup the poms so that rebuilding one of the modules will also trigger the distribution module to build in one build command instead of two separate build commands?

Comment: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use things like this:

```
mvn -pl module-2 -amd
```

`-amd` is an abbreviation for `also-make-dependents`.

from the root folder. This will build only `module-2` and all modules which depend on `module-2`. If you have correctly defined a dependency from your `distribution module` to `module-2` which is necessary.

Comment: Hoho, this actually works and is configurable in an IDE Run config. Thanks heaps!